# Novo Visual Studio Code

Tags: ftp

Estou iniciando no uso do editor de texto da Microsoft Visual Studio Code e estou sentindo falta de um plugin para sftp. Alguém que tenha conhecimento poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Por estar na versão `Preview` ainda não existem Plugins para ele.

Comment: Poxa que pena. Estava adorando ele mas não vou deixar o bom e velho sublime nesse momento.

Comment: Também estava testando ele, é muito bom, mas a microsoft ainda não libero pra poder criar plugins. O que é uma pena, mas fazer o que né, vamos esperar!!

Comment: O Visual Studio Code tem um "**user voice**", onde você pode ajudar a reforçar o pedido por determinadas funcionalidades, basta acessar: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code.